# Get Battery Information reportUpdated MVVM windows 10

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp

```
As I can call reportUpdated event from my ViewModel?
```

```
<code>
        public MainPage() 
        { 
            this.InitializeComponent(); 
            Battery.AggregateBattery.ReportUpdated += AggregateBattery_ReportUpdated; 
        } 
 </code>
```

[Here is a clear example of how to do this work. The problem is how to make this functionality but with a MVVM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/En-us/Es-fes/library/mt227653.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of options...

1. Attach the event handler inside the VM instead of using code-behind. EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, this is not the cleanest MVVM solution ever. A cleaner way would be to have some sort of platform independent interface (IAggregateBattery) in your VM and provide a platform implementation via constructor injection.
2. Invoke a method on your VM from AggregateBattery_ReportUpdated.
3. Send a message when the event happens with the event information using some sort of messenger (MVVM Light has it, other frameworks probably do too).

Comment: 1. Is not MVVM because the view model depends on FW specific code, 2. Good when battery changed is only needed in one VM, 3. Good when multiple VM listen for the change (message registration is global)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

In the constructor the my ViewModel

```
    <code>
    public MainViewModel()
    {
    //The firs time, launch to method for get the current status battery
            this.RequestAggregateBatteryReport();
    // This event is launch each time, when the status battery change
            Battery.AggregateBattery.ReportUpdated += AggregateBattery_ReportUpdated1;

        }

        private async void AggregateBattery_ReportUpdated1(Battery sender, object args)
            {
    //The Dispatcher is used when in other thread because is important use the other thread for avoid issue.
Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                () =>
                {
                    RequestAggregateBatteryReport();
                });
        }

   private void RequestAggregateBatteryReport()
        {
            // Create aggregate battery object
            var aggBattery = Battery.AggregateBattery;

            // Get report
            var report = aggBattery.GetReport();

            // Update UI
            AddReportUI(report, aggBattery.DeviceId);
        }

        private void AddReportUI(BatteryReport report, string DeviceID)
        {
            this.BatteryEnergy = new BatteryEnergy();

            // Disable progress bar if values are null
            if ((report.FullChargeCapacityInMilliwattHours == null) ||
                (report.RemainingCapacityInMilliwattHours == null))
            {

                this.BatteryEnergy.ProgressBarMaxium = 0.0;
                this.BatteryEnergy.ProgressBarValue = 0.0;
                this.BatteryEnergy.ProgressBarPorcent = "N/A";
            }
            else
            {


                this.BatteryEnergy.ProgressBarMaxium = Convert.ToDouble(report.FullChargeCapacityInMilliwattHours);
                this.BatteryEnergy.ProgressBarValue = Convert.ToDouble(report.RemainingCapacityInMilliwattHours);
                this.BatteryEnergy.ProgressBarPorcent = ((Convert.ToDouble(report.RemainingCapacityInMilliwattHours) / Convert.ToDouble(report.FullChargeCapacityInMilliwattHours)) * 100).ToString("F2") + "%";
            }
        }
```